# I can't insert a json on MongoDB with PHP script

Tags: php, json, mongodb

```
<?php
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    try {

        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
        or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($link,'classicmodels5') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');

           $query = "select c.customerNumber,c.customerName,c.city as customerCity, c.country as customerCountry,c.salesRepEmployeeNumber from customers as c";
           $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
                   $isFirst=0;
                   $isFirst2=0;
                   $isFirst3=0;
                   $isFirst4=0;
                   $json="";
                    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                         $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

                             $isFirst2=0;
                            $isFirst3=0;
                            $isFirst4=0;
                            extract($fila);

                            $json = $json."{";

                            //$json = $json.",{";
                            $json = $json.'"customerNumber":'.$fila["customerNumber"].',';
                            $json = $json.'"customerName":"'.$fila["customerName"].'",';
                            $json = $json.'"city":"'.$fila["customerCity"].'",';
                            $json = $json.'"country":"'.$fila["customerCountry"].'"';

                            //INICIO:INSERTAR PAYMENTS
                            $query2 = "select  p.checkNumber,p.amount from payments as p where p.customerNumber=".$fila["customerNumber"];
                            $result2 = mysqli_query($link,$query2);
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0){
                                $json=$json.',"payments":[';
                            }
                            while ($fila2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                                extract($fila2);
                                if($isFirst2==1){
                                   $json = $json.",{";
                                }else{
                                   $json = $json."{";
                                }
                                     $json = $json.'"checkNumber":"'.$fila2["checkNumber"].'",';
                                     $json = $json.'"amount":"'.$fila2["amount"].'"}';
                                $isFirst2=1;

                            }
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0){
                                $json=$json.']';
                            }
                            //FIN:INSERTAR PAYMENTS
                            //INICIO: INSERTAR EMPLOYEE
                            $query3 = "SELECT e.employeeNumber,e.lastName,e.extension,e.officeCode FROM employees as e where e.employeeNumber=".$fila["salesRepEmployeeNumber"];
                            $result3 = mysqli_query($link,$query3);
                                if(mysqli_num_rows($result3)>0){
                                    $json=$json.',"employees":[';
                                }
                                while ($fila3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
                                extract($fila3);
                                if($isFirst3==1){
                                   $json = $json.",{";
                                }else{
                                   $json = $json."{";
                                }
                                   $json = $json.'"employeeNumber":"'.$fila3["employeeNumber"].'",';
                                   $json = $json.'"lastName":"'.$fila3["lastName"].'",';
                                   $json = $json.'"extension":"'.$fila3["extension"].'"';
                                   //INICIO:INSERTAR OFFICE

                                    $query4 = "SELECT o.officeCode,o.city,o.country FROM offices as o where o.officeCode=".$fila3["officeCode"];
                                    $result4 = mysqli_query($link,$query4);    
                                     if(mysqli_num_rows($result4)>0){
                                         $json=$json.',"officeCode":';
                                     }
                                     while ($fila4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) {
                                     extract($fila4);
                                      if($isFirst4==1){
                                        $json = $json.",{";
                                     }else{
                                        $json = $json."{";
                                     }
                                       $json = $json.'"officeCode":"'.$fila4["officeCode"].'",';
                                       $json = $json.'"city":"'.$fila4["city"].'",';
                                       $json = $json.'"country":"'.$fila4["country"].'"}';

                                      $isFirst4=1;
                                     }

                                    //FIN:INSERTAR OFFICE

                                 $isFirst3=1;

                                }
                                if(mysqli_num_rows($result3)>0){
                                $json=$json.'}]';
                            }
                            //FIN:INSERTAR EMPLOYEE

                            $json = $json.'}';
                            echo $json."</br>";


                            //Hacer el insert 
                            $bulk->insert(json_decode($json));
                            $resultFinal = $manager->executeBulkWrite('test.prueba3', $bulk);
                            $json="";

                            $isFirst=1;
                        }
                        $json = str_replace("'", " ", $json);
                        echo $json;
                //echo $json;
       /* $bulk->insert(json_decode($json));
        $resultFinal = $manager->executeBulkWrite('test.customers', $bulk);
        var_dump($resultFinal);*/
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "EXCEPTION: ".$e->getMessage(), "\n";
        exit;
    }

?>
```

When I do the inserted, for every time I finish the first loop, I get the following error, I do not understand if it is because the JSON is wrong or should be inserted in another way

```
    Warning: MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite::insert() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp2\htdocs\prac\index.php on line 111

EXCEPTION: Cannot do an empty bulk write
```

I need every time I finish the first loop insert the JSON document for in the next lap add another, I get that error but when validating my json in JSONLint, I get that is valid. is a migration from MySQL to MongoDB.

This is the JSON that gives error, which I think is correctly written, where do you think this error? Thank you

```
{"customerNumber":144,"customerName":"Volvo Model Replicas, Co","city":"Lule�","country":"Sweden","payments":[{"checkNumber":"IR846303","amount":"36005.71"},{"checkNumber":"LA685678","amount":"7674.94"}],"employees":[{"employeeNumber":"1504","lastName":"Jones","extension":"x102","officeCode":{"officeCode":"7","city":"London","country":"UK"}}]}
```

Comment: Seems the JSON is not parsing correctly by the error message. But there simply is no need to do this. The MongoDB drivers actually work with PHP Data structures. You seem to think that you need JSON and are building data into JSON strings, but you simply don't need to do that.

Comment: Look at the edit please, that is the JSON that gives me error, I think it is well, that should change to be inserted? All the others are inserted and I see them equal

Comment: Read the comment please. **Don't build a JSON String**. Just use the PHP data as a natural `array()` or `[]` structure and insert it.

Comment: BTW. You're also using the wrong driver. You're attempting to use the core driver when you what you really want is the [PHPLIB Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/) which has a common API with other language implementations. The methods you should be using are [`MongoDB\Collection::bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-bulkWrite/) or really in your context just [`MongoDB::Collection::insertOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-insertOne/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your code to this:

```
<?php
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
try {

    $json='{"customerNumber":144,"customerName":"Volvo Model Replicas, Co","city":"Lule�","country":"Sweden","payments":[{"checkNumber":"IR846303","amount":"36005.71"},{"checkNumber":"LA685678","amount":"7674.94"}],"employees":[{"employeeNumber":"1504","lastName":"Jones","extension":"x102","officeCode":{"officeCode":"7","city":"London","country":"UK"}}]}';
        $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;


        echo $json."</br>";


        //Hacer el insert
        $bulk->insert(json_decode($json));
        $resultFinal = $manager->executeBulkWrite('test.prueba3', $bulk);
        $json="";

        $isFirst=1;

}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "EXCEPTION: ".$e->getMessage(), "\n";
    exit;
}
```

And is printed JSON and saved data do mongodb

```
> db.prueba3.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b13bbda65b9bb1f3e6b9922"),
    "customerNumber" : 144,
    "customerName" : "Volvo Model Replicas, Co",
    "city" : "Lule�",
    "country" : "Sweden",
    "payments" : [
        {
            "checkNumber" : "IR846303",
            "amount" : "36005.71"
        },
        {
            "checkNumber" : "LA685678",
            "amount" : "7674.94"
        }
    ],
    "employees" : [
        {
            "employeeNumber" : "1504",
            "lastName" : "Jones",
            "extension" : "x102",
            "officeCode" : {
                "officeCode" : "7",
                "city" : "London",
                "country" : "UK"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please confirm that this example works in your case. If not you can compare `$json` that is defined in this example and your `$json` before comment `//Hacer el insert`.

Any way if is it possible please isolate your problem. Including such huge amount of code is not so useful as smaller. To help other to response you can use exemplary data instead of pasting code with selects from database.

Concatenating JSON from string is very bad practice. Imagine that one of your string contains character like this: "{". Did you escaped it?

Potentially problem can be connected with encoding `Lule�`. You are using Windows, maybe your text of your code or SQL database has encoding different than UTF-8.